# How to write test result in CSV file using selenium

Tags: csv, selenium, data-driven-tests

I have to add result at the last column of each row. I have to test user successfully login with correct email and password the "PASS" is append to last else "FAIL" and go with the second row and check the result of each row.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation\\Selenium Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

// This will load csv file
CSVReader reader = null;
try{
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\src\\com\\elements\\demo.csv"));
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String[] cell;

while ((cell=reader.readNext())!=null){
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        String emailid=cell[i];
        String password=cell[i+1];

        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(emailid);
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();

        String outputFile = "C:\\Users\\src\\com\\elements\\demo.csv";
        try {
            // use FileWriter constructor that specifies open for appending
            CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true),',');
            if(driver.getTitle().equals("Log1 in to Facebook | Facebook"))
            {
                csvOutput.write("Pass"); //Your selenium result.
                //csvOutput.endRecord();              
                //csvOutput.close();
            }
            else if (driver.getTitle().equals("Log in to Facebook | Facebook"))
            {
                csvOutput.write("userName");
                csvOutput.write("password");
                csvOutput.write("Fail"); //Your selenium result.
                csvOutput.endRecord();              
                csvOutput.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
String outputFile = "test.csv";

// before we open the file check to see if it already exists
boolean alreadyExists = new File(outputFile).exists();

try {
    // use FileWriter constructor that specifies open for appending
    CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true),',');

    // if the file didn't already exist then we need to write out the header line
    if (!alreadyExists){
        csvOutput.write("result");
        csvOutput.endRecord();
    }
    // else assume that the file already has the correct header line
    // write out a few records
    csvOutput.write("userName");
    csvOutput.write("password");
    csvOutput.write("Pass/Fail"); //Your selenium result.
    csvOutput.endRecord();              
    csvOutput.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OR
If we want to use writeNext() method which take string array as a parameter then

```
String csv = "D:\\test.csv";
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
data.add(new String[] {"India", "New Delhi"});
data.add(new String[] {"United States", "Washington D.C"});
data.add(new String[] {"Germany", "Berlin"});

writer.writeAll(data);

writer.close();
```

Try other option.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/test.csv",false);

        writer.append(" ");
        writer.append(',');

        writer.append("UserName");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Password");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Pass/Fail");
        writer.append('\n');

        //generate whatever data you want

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
```

Comment: String outputFile = "demo.csv";
try {

    CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true),',');
    if(driver.getTitle().equals("Log1 in to Facebook | Facebook"))
    {
     csvOutput.write("Pass"); //Your selenium result.
    }
    else if (driver.getTitle().equals("Log in to Facebook | Facebook"))
    {
     csvOutput.endRecord();
     csvOutput.write("Fail"); //Your selenium result.
     csvOutput.close(); 
    }

And i got below the output
test@test.com,password
test1@test.com,password2
Fail
Fail

I need write to fail/pass at the end of each line

Comment: And i got below the output
**test@test.com,password
test1@test.com,password2
Fail
Fail**

I need write to fail/pass at the end of each line. Its

Comment: please comment the endRecord() fucntion and check it again.

Comment: Already try with this *comment the endRecord()* but same issue

Comment: csvOutput.writeNext("userName");  "writeNext" showing me an error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method writeNext(String) is undefined for the type CsvWriter

 at com.elements.Csv.main(Csv.java:58)

Comment: Edit the code. Give the other option. Check it once.

Comment: I edited the code with the writeNext() button and still you didn't get the proper result ?

Comment: No its not working, I edited the code and add the result image. please look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164393/discussion-between-hiten-and-darshit-shah).